# How to change root url in wordpress for existing blog

Tags: wordpress, url

I did mistake and didnt change my root URL when started work with WordPress, for now I have my blog with about 30 pages and I need change root URL.

- My wordpress located:

  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\wordpress`
- My blog stays as theme under:

  `...\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\myblog`
- My domain URL:

  `http://www.myblog.co.il/wordpress/wp-admin`
- `index.php` located:

  `...\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\myblog\index.php`

when I run my main page aka `index.php` I see `http://www.myblog.co.il/wordpress`
therefore all generated  permalinks look like:
 `http://www.myblog.co.il/wordpress/?page_id=158` ... .

**The main quiestion is: How to change:**

`http://www.myblog.co.il/wordpress` **to** '`http://www.myblog.co.il/`' **in order to change automatically all permalinks?** a.e. `http://www.myblog.co.il/?page_id=158` ...

I saw enough solutions how to do that from start but not when blog is ready.

Please, help me to find proper solution.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of you'll have to configure a virtual host in Apache to match the domain to your htdocs\wordpress folder and not just to \htdocs. You can read more on vhosts in apache [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/).

Since Wordpress saves all URLS in their absolute form to the database, you'll have to manually fix this by replaceing the URLS in the database. Assuming you're running MySQL and the current URL to your blog is http://www.myblog.co.il/wordpress, you can use these queries:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'http://www.myblog.co.il/wordpress', 'http://www.myblog.co.il');
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE(guid, 'http://www.myblog.co.il/wordpress', 'http://www.myblog.co.il');
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'http://www.myblog.co.il' WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
```

this does not only fix hardcoded links but it also fixes custom links inside the content of your pages and posts.

Answer (score 1):

You tried changing `siteurl` and `home` in your `options` table?

I'm not sure of understanding what you mean, but the page on [Moving WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) might help you.

Comment: (1) I can't change siteurl or home because after that I can block myself to domain page (2) i cant move my wordpress because one of conditions is to stay with the same URL and I want to change it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming nothing else is in root `htdocs` directory, i.e. if you go to `http://www.myblog.co.il/` nothing should show up, update your URL via the admin backend (or via MySQL `wp_options` table), and move everything inside of the `wordpress` directory back into the `htdocs` directory.

Comment: `myblog` is theme and located under `wordpress\wp-content\themes\`. If ill move all content of theme to htdocs directory, how can I configure wordpress to use theme located under `htdocs`? thanks

Comment: No, don't move the theme folder, move the entire wordpress folder. So instead of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\wordpress` you have `C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs` containing your base wordpress installation, and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\wp-content\themes\myblog` being your new theme location. You're just taking the contents of the `wordpress` directory, cutting them, and pasting them into the `htdocs` folder, then deleting an empty `wordpress` folder.